# Difference between innerhtml and outerhtml in cocoa WebView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

I am using cocoa webview for rich text editing in my application. Just confused with innerHtml and outerHtml method avaiable in webkit.

Can anyone explain what is the difference between

```
[(DOMHTMLElement *)[[[webView mainFrame] DOMDocument] documentElement] outerHTML];
```

AND

```
[(DOMHTMLElement *)[[[webView mainFrame] DOMDocument] documentElement] outerText];
```

Answer (score 17):

**innerHTML** is a property of a DOM element that represents the HTML
inside the element, i.e. between the opening and closing tags.  It has
been widely copied, however implementations vary (probably  because it
has no published standard[1]) particularly in how they treat element
attributes.

**outerHTML** is similar to innerHTML, it is an element property that
includes the opening an closing tags as well as the content.   It
hasn't been as widely copied as innerHTML so it remains more-or-less
IE only.

```
<p id="pid">welcome</p>

innerHTML of element "pid" == welcome
outerHTML of element "pid" == <p id="pid">welcome</p>
```

and whereAs

**innerText**   The textual content of the container.

**outerText**   Same as innerText when accessed for read; replaces the whole element when assigned a new value.

```
<p id="pid">welcome</p>

innerText of element "pid" == welcome
outerText of element "pid" == welcome
```

Answer (score 6):

Suppose we have a page loaded to webview with html

```
<html>
<head><title>Your Title</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p id="para" >hi <b>Your_Name</b></p>
</body>
<html>
```

NOW.

```
[(DOMHTMLElement *)[[webView mainFrame] DOMDocument] documentElement]
```

will returen the DOMHTMLElement "html" and

**outerHTML** will return the complete html as

```
<html>
<head><title>Your Title</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Heading</hi>
<p id="para">hi <b>Your_Name</b></p>
</body>
<html>
```

**outerText** will return html as

Heading
hi Your_Name

for example if we take example of p tag in this case

```
outerHTML will return - <p id="para">hi <b>Your_Name</b></p>

outerText will return - hi Your_Name

innerHTML will return - hi <b>Your_Name</b>

innerText will return - hi Your_Name
```

i have explained it with the help of example where definition for these 4 terms already explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>innerHTML and outerHTML | Javascript Usages</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="replace">REPLACE By inner or outer HTML</div>
<script>
userwant = "inner";
userwant = "outer";
if (userwant = "inner") {
document.querySelector("#replace").innerHTML;
// this will remove just message: 'REPLACE By inner or outer HTML' //
} else if (userwant = "outer") {
document.querySelector("#replace").outerHTML;
// this will remove all element <div> ~ </div> by the message: 'REPLACE By inner or outer HTML' //
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```