# With javascript selenium webdriver, how do I get the HTML of the DOM during my test?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, npm, protractor, e2e-testing

We're using the Selenium webdriver manager v 12.1.7 with protractor 5.4.3 to help develop end-to-end tests for our Angular 9 application.  I have this set up in my package.json for running our e2e tests ...

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "install-puppeteer": "cd node_modules/puppeteer && npm run install",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "npm run install-puppeteer && ng e2e"
```

I would like to see the DOM at a particular point in my test.  I tried this

```
const pageSource = await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('body'))), waitTimeout);
console.log('pageSource: ', pageSource.innerHTML);
```

but when the test runs, the above dies with

```
e2e/src/pages/devices.page.ts:125:44 - error TS2339: Property 'innerHTML' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

125     console.log('pageSource: ', pageSource.innerHTML);
```

What's the proper way to get the DOM HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log(await browser.getPageSource())
```

why can't you use getPagesource

you can print inner and outerhtml as follows:

```
console.log(await element(by.css('body')).getAttribute('outerHTML'))
console.log(await element(by.css('body')).getAttribute('innerHTML'))
console.log(await browser.getPageSource())
```

if page source is not what you are looking for then outerHTML would be the one you need as

> innerHTML is a property of a DOM element that represents the HTML
> inside the element, i.e. between the opening and closing tags. ...
> outerHTML is similar to innerHTML, it is an element property that
> includes the opening an closing tags as well as the content.J

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256102/difference-between-innerhtml-and-outerhtml-in-cocoa-webview#:~:text=innerHTML%20is%20a%20property%20of,the%20opening%20and%20closing%20tags.&text=outerHTML%20is%20similar%20to%20innerHTML,as%20well%20as%20the%20content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256102/difference-between-innerhtml-and-outerhtml-in-cocoa-webview#:%7E:text=innerHTML%20is%20a%20property%20of,the%20opening%20and%20closing%20tags.&text=outerHTML%20is%20similar%20to%20innerHTML,as%20well%20as%20the%20content).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `.getAttribute('innerHTML')`. So you can console.log what is below.

```
console.log('pageSource: ', pageSource.getAttribute('innerHTML'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe pageSource will return a string object, try just this:

```
 console.log('pageSource: ', pageSource);
```